# My question is that I am getting an error(Timed out waiting for driver server to start for chrome browser)

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Eclipse Luna with windows 10-64 bit, selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59 and selenium-java-3.141.59. 
I have write a simple program to hit the url .But I am getting this error:

> [13552:3540:0515/184943.562:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(21)] Unable to
>   move the cache: 0
>   [13552:3540:0515/184943.562:ERROR:cache_util.cc(141)] Unable to move
>   cache folder C:\Users\RChauh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache to
>   C:\Users\RChauh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
>   [13552:3540:0515/184943.562:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(185)] Unable to create
>   cache [13552:3540:0515/184943.562:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(623)]
>   Shader Cache Creation failed: -2 Opening in existing browser session.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Build info: version:
>   '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System
>   info: host: 'LAPTOP-3VFBUTNB', ip: '192.168.1.102', os.name: 'Windows
>   10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>     at helloWorld.java.main(java.java:11) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
>   for [http://localhost:32149/status] to be available after 20016 ms    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
>     ... 10 more

```
package helloWorld;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class java {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        System.out.println("LoginPage");
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `webdriver.chrome.driver` property to point to the `chromedriver.exe`, not to `chrome.exe`

1. Download the relevant [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) package for your Chrome browser version
2. Unpack the archive somewhere
3. Amend the `webdriver.chrome.driver` property to point to the `chromedriver.exe` from step 2
4. That's it, you should be good to go now

Check out [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome -> Getting Started](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) for more detailed information if needed.

---

Until it's not too late be aware of [Page Object design pattern](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern), it is some form of Selenium scripting Best Practice which allows to split test logic from UI elements definitions making your tests easier to develop and especially maintain. Check out [Design Patterns - Page Object Model](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) for more detailed information and example test project.